# How to make a particular element in Bootstrap not use the theme style?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap with the extra theme provided `bootstrap-theme.min.css`, however sometimes there are elements where I would really want to use the traditional Bootstrap style. My main concern now is to use the traditional Panel header style of a particular Panel. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Open up an unminified bootstrap-theme.css put another class WITH the other classes:

```
.theme.panel-X {...}
.theme.btn {}
.theme.btn-primary {}
```

and on and on. If elements are children of the style, then it's

```
   .theme .child-component {....}
```

Then in your html, put that class - "`.theme`" in this example -- on all the components you want to use with the theme and don't put that class on other components that you don't want to use it on.